# how to create a customized table for report using rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

i'm new to rmarkdown. i want to create a table for a report in r markdown it will be some thing like below. Is there a  way to create table like this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do just about anything with the excellent {gt} package.

https://gt.rstudio.com/

and

https://gt.rstudio.com/articles/intro-creating-gt-tables.html